# How to insert value in Database every time when checkbox is checked and unchecked without clicking submit button of form

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

```html
// JSP Page //
<%
                        while(resultSet.next()) {
                        int ab = ((Number) resultSet.getInt(3)).intValue();
                    %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= resultSet.getString(2) %></td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="switch1">
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="check(<%= resultSet.getInt(1) %>)" name="mc_deactive<%= resultSet.getInt(1) %>" id="mc_deactive<%= resultSet.getInt(1) %>" <%= ab==1?"checked":"" %> >
                                <span class="slider round" title="Disabled"></span>
                        </label>
                                
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function check(id)
                                    {
                                        if(document.getElementById("mc_deactive"+id).checked==true)
                                        {
                                            <% 
                                                int b = 0;
                                                int ii = ((Number) resultSet.getInt(1)).intValue();
                                                actDct.active(ii);
                                            %>
                                            
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            int ii = ((Number) resultSet.getInt(1)).intValue();
                                                actDct.deactive(ii);
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                </script>
                                
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="m_m_c_edit.jsp?id=<%= resultSet.getInt(1) %>">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-xs-3">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &NoBreak; Edit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    
// Java Class //
public void active(int id)
    {
        int set = 1;
        int i = id;
        System.out.println(id);
        dBConnection.openConnection();
        String update = "update meal_category_master SET is_active = '1' WHERE meal_category_id = "+i;
        int a = 0;
        a = dBConnection.crud(update);
    }
    
    public void deactive(int id)
    {
        int d = 0;
        int i = id;
        dBConnection.openConnection();
        String update = "update meal_category_master SET is_active = '0' WHERE meal_category_id = "+i;
        int a = 0;
        a = dBConnection.crud(update);
        dBConnection.closeConnection();
    }
```

I have a checkbox designed as switch.
Whenever the jsp page loads i want to check the checkbox if "active" column of database have value 1 and uncheck if value is 0.
And another i also want that at every time when that checkbox is checked 1 should be inserted in database's active column for that particular row and 0 when checkbox is unchecked.

I have written some code,which is as below.
It updates the value of active column but instead of single row it updates value of all rows`

Comment: there is no code. you can add a `ItemChanged` listener to the checkbox and fire the querys every time the states changes

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: sorry....i am adding it

Answer (score 2):

You can add Ajax call for onChange evenet of checkbox.

CheckBox

write down ajax call to update DB value in updateCheckboxStatus function.

Comment: but i don't know ajax. Can please write code for it.

Comment: @ShaffanShaikh Then u have to learn Ajax else u will never be a good web developer.

Comment: If you know normal request then you can learn Ajax easily. Ajax is basically do communication with server, exchange data and update specific elements of web page without refreshing the whole page.